# How to use value of one setting property to specify value of another in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to show a vertical ruler in editor bound to the value of `editor.wordWrapColumn`. So I need to specify in array `editor.rulers` value of `editor.wordWrapColumn`. Could I bound it?

Comment: what data types does the setting `editor.rulers` allow

Comment: I think only numbers.